# How to create multiple models using a model component without defining separate state variables for each one in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following model dialog box:

```
// Modal.tsx

import React, { ReactNode } from "react";

interface ModalType {
  children?: ReactNode;
  isOpen: boolean;
  toggle: () => void;
}

export default function Modal(props: ModalType) {
  return (
    <>
      {props.isOpen && (
        <div className="modal-overlay" onClick={props.toggle}>
          <div onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()} className="modal-box max-w-md bg-[#323F5F]">
            {props.children}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

and I access this model dialog like the following:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Index = () => {

    const [isOpen, setisOpen] = useState(false);
    
    <div onClick={() => setisOpen(!isOpen)}>Dialog 1</div>
    <div onClick={() => setisOpen(!isOpen)}>Dialog 2</div>
    
    <Modal isOpen={isOpen} toggle={() => setisOpen(!isOpen)}>
     Dialog 1 content
    </Modal>

    <Modal isOpen={isOpen} toggle={() => setisOpen(!isOpen)}>
     Dialog 2 content
    </Modal>

}
```

Here, I am trying to create multiple models using the model component, without defining separate state variables for each one. Is it possible to access each model separately without the need for a separate state variable for each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use an array in the state variable, with element `i` indicating the open state of modal `i`:

```js
const Index = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState([false, false]);
    const toggleOpen = (i) => setOpen(open => {
        const newOpen = [...open];
        newOpen[i] != open[i];
        return newOpen;
    });

    return <div>
        <div onClick={() => toggleOpen(0)}>
            Dialog 1
        </div>
        <div onClick={() => toggleOpen(1)}>
            Dialog 2
        </div>
        <Modal isOpen={open[0]} toggle={() => toggleOpen(0)}>
            Dialog 1 content
        </Modal>    
        <Modal isOpen={open[1]} toggle={() => toggleOpen(1)}>
            Dialog 2 content
        </Modal>
    </div>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly - you can always create a object i.e `Record<number, boolean>` or array to keep each state for Modal separate in one `useState`. Then you would create a component which maps over this state and creates modal if it meet it's `isOpen` condition. The toggle function would look like this, but you could always create the toggles dynamically.

```
const [modals, setModals] = useState([false, false]);

function handleToggleFirstModal(newState) { setModals(prevState => [!prevState[0], ...prevState]) };
```